# Is there a way for a text to go up on P5.js so it makes room for more text?

Tags: javascript, processing, p5.js

I am trying to use a typewriting effect for a presentation on p5.js. What i have already is a long text writen on the canvas. When the text gets on the limit of the height I am not really sure how to meke for the text that is already writen to go up and slowly disappear like credit films or just write a whole new text on a new canvas.
her

```js
let dani = 'hola mundo...................\n..........................\n......................................\n...........................\n.............................\n.........................................................\n.................................\n.................................\n.................................\n......................................................\n...................\n..................\n....................\n....................\n......................\n..............................\n..............................\n...............................\n................................\n............................\n............................\n...........................\n...........................\n............................\n.............................\n..............................\n...............................\n...........................\n.....................................'

let index = 0
let lastMillis = 0


function setup() {
  createCanvas(800, 600);
  textAlign(LEFT, TOP)
  textSize(30)
  frameRate(20)
     
}

function draw() {
  background(220);

  stroke(0)
 text(dani.substring(0,index), 0,10, width, height + textAscent())
  scrollY = scrollY + 40
  if(millis() > lastMillis + 300){
    index = index + 1 
    //PALABRAS COMPLETAS 
    
        // while(dani.charAt(index) != ' ' &&
        //       index < dani.length){
        //  index = index + 1;
        // }
   
  
   
    lastMillis = millis()
    
  }
  
}

console.log(dani)
```

Comment: The code doesn't appear to work currently. I suggest fixing it, then making an attempt at scrolling it. Thanks.

Comment: @ggorlen I have checked and the code is working

Comment: Where do you get the scrollbar? I tried running your code in P5.js editor and there's a moment that it just writes outside the canvas.

Answer (score 0):

If you can avoid text wrapping it's relatively easy. You can just calculate the height based on the number of lines so far and translate to prevent the bottom line from going off screen.

If you absolutely must have wrapping text it is more complicated because you need to determine where text has wrapped to calculate the height. The underlying Canvas API has support for measuring text width: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/measureText which would be theoretically useful in determining when/where text wraps so that you can correctly determine the height of the text.

Here's an example of the simpler case where text wrapping is disabled.

```js
let dani = 'hola mundo...................\n..........................\n......................................\n...........................\n.............................\n.........................................................\n.................................\n.................................\n.................................\n......................................................\n...................\n..................\n....................\n....................\n......................\n..............................\n..............................\n...............................\n................................\n............................\n............................\n...........................\n...........................\n............................\n.............................\n..............................\n...............................\n...........................\n.....................................'

let index = 0
let lastMillis = 0

function setup() {
  createCanvas(400, 200);
  textAlign(LEFT, TOP)
  textSize(30)
  // frameRate(20)
}

function draw() {
  background(220);

  stroke(0)
  let str = dani.substring(0,index);
  let h = str.split('\n').length * textLeading();
  
  if (h > height - 30) {
   translate(0, - (h - (height - 30)));
  }
  
  text(str, 0, 10 /* , width, height + textAscent() */)
  scrollY = scrollY + 40
  if(millis() > lastMillis + 50){
    index = index + 1 
    //PALABRAS COMPLETAS 
    
        // while(dani.charAt(index) != ' ' &&
        //       index < dani.length){
        //  index = index + 1;
        // }
   
  
   
    lastMillis = millis()
    
  }
  
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/1.6.0/p5.js"></script>
```